# Handle a list fron api call

Tags: flutter

An api call returns a list (never more two postcodes)  [ postcode1, postcode2].. with a String name property.
The user need to choose one of the items from the list and that will be used as a parameter for another call. I'm serving up the two postcodes as `Text` widgets because the Objects have  string name property.But I really don't know how to implement this functionally...ie if I have the two text widgets on screen,I want the widgets to disappear and the chosen one in a new `Text` widget I've tried with `FutureBuilder` but this doesn't seem to work very well for my use case because for the first api call I have the user enter data to `Textfield` and then make the call. Any ideas..and I'm open to different approaches?

Comment: Could you share some code you have tried to implement? It is hard to understand the process you are describing. How is a postcode chosen? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: try SteamBuilder if your value for querying is constantly changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)? That state management solution would give you everything you need.

You display widgets based on states that are yielded from events. 
In your particular case, the initial event would be the one in which you make the API call. Then you yield a state with the response data which is rendered on the UI side. The widgets are displayed however you want, depending on the state (you could use Visibility, conditional statements, custom widgets etc.)

Another event would be triggered when the user chooses an option. You immediately yield a state that hides the unwanted widget, and proceed with your logic.

You haven't really given a specific example, so this is the most I can help for now.